# Jackson can't serialize Object when contained In Map<String, Object>

Tags: java, jackson, jersey, codahale-metrics

When requesting a single `com.codahale.metrics.Meter` via Jersey-REST-Service, Jackson is doing just fine and serializes the Meter to (formatting done by me)

```
{
  "count":0,
  "fiveMinuteRate":0.0,
  "fifteenMinuteRate":0.0,
  "oneMinuteRate":0.0,
  "meanRate":0.0
}
```

When requesting the same Meter contained inside a `Map<String, Metric>`, Jackson complaines:

> No serializer found for class com.codahale.metrics.Meter and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["testMetric"])

I could just make my resource-method return the String that the `ObjectMapper` is able to create (see below), but I would like to keep my method returning `Map<String, Metric>`.

Why can't Jackson figure it out on its own?
How can I make Jackson realize that it knows how to serialize the Object?
How can I check the configuration of the ObjectMapper used by Jersey?

I have verified that the Map is not empty and that the `Meter` is acutally there.

When I create a vanilla `ObjectMapper` and serialize the Map

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValueAsString( myMetricMap );
```

it works just fine:

```
{
  "testMetric":
  {
    "count":0,
    "fiveMinuteRate":0.0,
    "fifteenMinuteRate":0.0,
    "oneMinuteRate":0.0,
    "meanRate":0.0
  }
}
```

`dropwizard-metrics` provides a `metrics-json`-Package that includes Serializers for Metrics and HealthChecks. Unfortunately, due to a dependency mess, I cannot use it.

EDIT:
As it was suggested in the comments, I've tried to serialize a `Map<String, Meter>` - and it worked!

To summarize:

```java
public interface Metric {
  // Empty Marker Interface
}

public class Meter implements Metric {
  ...
}

@Path("/")
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
public MetricsResource {
  @GET
  @Path("metric/{metricName}")
  public Metric getMetric( @PathParam String metricName ) {
    // Works!
    return MetricsService.getMetric( metricName );
  }

  @GET
  @Path("metricsAsString")
  public String getMetricsAsString()
  {
    // Works!
    return (new ObjectMapper()).writeValueAsString(
        MetricsService.getMetrics());
  }

  @GET
  @Path("meters")
  public Map<String, Meter> getMeters()
  {
    // Works!
    return MetricsService.getMeters();
  }

  @GET
  @Path("metrics")
  public Map<String, Metric> getMetrics()
  {
    // Fails!
    return metricsService.getMetrics();
}
```

I suppose that jackson is not determining the concrete Type when implicitly serializing, but is trying to serialize based on the (marker) Interface `Metric`.

Comment: `Metric` and `Meter` are two different classes, try returning `Metric` class from your controller to see if it serializes correctly.

Comment: That's true. `Meter` ist implementing `Metric` though. I did what you asked and now it is serializing correctly.

I was under the impression that Jackson will be able to determine the concrete type during runtime and serialize based on the concrete type. at least this is what it did when being called from the `ObjectMapper` and from the Single-Object-Resource. I Always return `Metric` and never explicitly `Meter`.